# Directions using location cordinates using ArcGis Javascript API

Tags: maps, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Anybody know how to show driving directions between two points using ArcGis javascript api with location co ordinates only (not with place name or address)

I need to implement driving directions to a particular point(point B) from current user location(point A, I have the user location from browser) where the destination Point B's latitude and longitude is stored in my database,,,

pls help '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RouteTask to get the result.

```
var routeParams = new RouteParameters();
routeParams.stops = new FeatureSet();
routeParams.returnRoutes = false;
routeParams.returnDirections = true;
routeParams.directionsLengthUnits = Units.MILES;
routeParams.outSpatialReference = new SpatialReference({ wkid:102100 });
```

if the locations are in lat long, convert it to WebMercator using webMercatorUtils

```
routeParams.stops.features.add(new Graphic(pointA));
routeParams.stops.features.add(new Graphic(pointB));
```

You can use your own service url here if you have one.

```
var routeTask = new RouteTask("http://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World");

routeTask .solve(routeParams, function(result){
     //handle route result.
}, function(err){
     //handle error
});
```

If you are using Directions dijit, it already has methods to add Point geometry. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/directions-amd.html#addstop

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: @T Kambi Thanks for your reply.. In my case the Directions dijit is more appropriate I guess and I am using that. I refered the addStop method documentation as well and it looks good. But it is not working for me...

Comment: @Jithin-kuriakose are you getting any error messages?